# AppSync and Push Notifications

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, push

I want to make my AWS AppSync app ready to push notifications for mobile apps(Android and iOS)
Where I have a GraphQL schema and Lambda as a data-source.
The problem is that I don't know what is the best solution for this.

do you think that:

- I should make the mobile app connect via a WebSocket and subscribe for the GraphQL subscriptions to listen for the pushed notifications?
- or I should use other services like AWS SNS or others with my AppSync ?
- or what do you suggest, what is the best practice to let my AppSync app serve push notifications ?

note : I build a chat application
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Aws Appsync is preferred when you need realtime and offline capabilities in your app, if I want only push notification the SNS is better than Aws Appsync